A script to use to git fetch to see if git pull is needed then create new archive of directory
The script is to update a group of repos and archives .bz2 of each repo. That uses git fetch to check if git pull is needed, then after each git pull the script backs up the old archive and creates a new one.
I have got it working to a point. Currently it makes new archives, even if git pull has not run. I want it to stop if git pull isn't needed and move onto next repo.
Below is the first 2 out of 25 repo's to update, PKGNAM s the beginning of each part of the script.
#!/bin/bash

# update-sources.sh script

SRCDIR=/home/darkside/Downloads/slack64-xfce4-source/xfce-master-build
LOG=$PKGNAM-updated.log

PKGNAM=exo-master
# git clone https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/exo.gi
cd $SRCDIR/exo/exo-master

fetch=$(git fetch)
if [[ -z "$fetch" ]]
then
    echo "$PKGNAM-Local Repo up to date, no git pull needed"
else
    git pull || echo "git pull required" || true | 2>&1 | tee $PKGNAM-$LOG
fi
cont=$(true)
if [[ -z "$cont" ]]
then
    cd ..
    mv *-master.tar.bz2 old-src-pkgs
    tar -cjf exo-master.tar.bz2 exo-master
    cd ..
fi

PKGNAM=garcon-master
# git clone https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/garcon.git
cd $SRCDIR/garcon/garcon-master

fetch=$(git fetch)
if [[ -z "$fetch" ]]
then
    echo "$PKGNAM-Local Repo up to date, no git pull needed"
else
    git pull || echo "git pull required" || true | 2>&1 | tee $PKGNAM-$LOG
fi
cont=$(true)
if [[ -z "$cont" ]]
then
    cd ..
    mv *-master.tar.bz2 old-src-pkgs
    tar -cjf garcon-master.tar.bz2 garcon-master
    cd ..
fi


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. Check out [ask]. You might want to read Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

To get some useful hints paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

thank you wjandrea that was fantastic advice and helped me no end. I also worked out I needed an "exit 0" after the first echo statement so the script ended as without it made new archives when git pull didn't run which was unnecessary.
